# 802.15.4 unslotted CSMA/CA implementation

Tags: networking, wireless, cortex-m

I want to implement 802.15.4 unslotted CSMA/CA.

I had read IEEE 802.15.4 document(2016), But i couldn't find anything related to 
implement 802.15.4 unslotted CSMA/CA.

There was only description about overall 802.15.4 not specification things about implementing.

I had searched it in google, there was only Z-Stack or TIMAC.

I'm using CC2538DK, there is RF module supporting 802.15.4 MAC.

So, I want to implement 802.15.4 unslotted CSMA/CA mode on Cortex-M3(CC2538).

Any advice or reference is very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the TIMAC first and see if will fit your use case. If not, it will at least provide an implementation that you can use as a reference.

Regarding the TIMAC, it is structured like:

- Upper/High-level MAC: Source provided. Mostly is just the IEEE specified API constants etc
- Middle MAC: Source NOT provided. TI provide pre-built binaries here (well, they did last time I used this library).
- Lower MAC / RF Driver: Source provided. This is the low level RF block drivers etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at riot-os.org or Contiki which provide a full open-source stack including unslotted IEEE 802.15.4 and many other nice things for building IoT applications.